# Numpy transpose weird output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transpose

```
np.array([3, 2, 3]).T == np.array([[3],[2],[1]])
```

outputs:

```
[[ True False  True]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```

Why isn't this equal and what does this output mean?

Comment: These arrays have a different number of dimensions, so comparing them for equality will create a broadcasting operation.

Comment: NumPy is an n-dimensional array library, not a matrix library. A NumPy transpose reverses the order of all dimensions an array actually has; if an array is not already 2D, it will not force the array to be 2D.

Comment: Did you look at `np.array([3, 2, 3]).T`?

Answer (score 2):

So you have two arrays: `np.array([3, 2, 3]).T` (which is identical to the non-tranposed version: `np.array([3, 2, 3])`), and `np.array([[3],[2],[1]])`. Let's look at each one:

```
>>> a = np.array([3, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([3, 2, 3])

>>> b = np.array([[3],[2],[1]])
>>> b
array([[3],
       [2],
       [1]])
```

Note how the first (`a`) is 1D, while the second (`b`) is 2D. Since they have different dimensions, trying to compare them will do what's called "numpy broadcasting", and it's a really cool feature.

To break it down:

```
>>> a == b
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Basically what the does, is for every item `E` in `b`, it checks if all the items in `a` are equal to `E`. To prove that:

```
>>> a == b[0]
array([ True, False,  True])

>>> a == b[1]
array([False,  True, False])

>>> a == b[2]
array([False, False, False])
```

Notice how the above arrays are identical to the whole array made by `a == b`. That's because `a == b` is a short, efficient form of doing the above.